# How to use FormControl statusChanges in angular2?

Tags: angular

i am new to angular2 and i want to trigger a function when the user selects some value in a dropDown. So i tried to implement statusChange of the FormControl class but it is not getting triggered,

> wonder how and when to use the statusChange in angular2
> this is my code

```
class policy{
 subCategory: FormControl = new FormControl();
 ngOnInit() {
            this.subCategory.statusChanges.subscribe(
                s => {
                    alert('success');
                }, e => {
                    alert('error');
                }, () => {
                    alert('complete');
                }
            );
        }
}
```

I thought by implementing statusChanges i can trigger the success function on every change of value on the dropdown, obviously it is now working.

**UPDATE 1**

I have updated the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xT2wUrKsy5vZ6lDniLj6?p=info)

Comment: If you want to know about value changes, you'd better of subscribing to `valueChanges` instead of `statusChanges`. StatusChanges is about `pristine`, `valid`, ...

Comment: ok, let me check and come back, thank you for your help

Comment: changing from statusChanges to valueChanges doesnt help me in any way, still i am not able to trigger the function

Comment: If you can provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce the problem, someone might be able to help. Your question doesn't provide enough information to diagnose the problem. There isn't even a dropdown mentioned in your code.

Comment: sorry for the delay, i have updated the plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/xT2wUrKsy5vZ6lDniLj6?p=info

Comment: The Plunker doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 24):

As the comments stated, you probably wanted `valueChanges` instead. However, for the thousands of other folks who arrived here from searching for how `statusChanges` works, here you go:

```
this.subCategory.statusChanges.subscribe( (status) => {
  console.log(status); //status will be "VALID", "INVALID", "PENDING" or "DISABLED"
})
```

[The docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges) describe those 4 possible values as follows:

> - VALID: This control has passed all validation checks.
> - INVALID: This control has failed at least one validation check.
> - PENDING: This control is in the midst of conducting a validation check.
> - DISABLED:This control is exempt from validation checks. These status values are mutually exclusive, so a control cannot be both valid AND invalid or invalid AND disabled.

Comment: I did this but keep getting error in console. Cannot read property 'statusChanges' of undefined.  I do have ViewChild and done subscribe in ngAfterViewInit.

Answer (score 7):

In Reactive forms `valueChanges` and `statusChanges` both looks very similar but serves two different purposes.

### statusChanges

`statusChanges` is a property of `AbstractControl` that emits an event every time when the validation status of the control is recalculated. There are few statuses which [is explained in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51506294/340046)

### valueChanges

`valueChanges` is a property of `AbstractControl` that emits an event every time when the value of control changes either using UI or programmatically.

Therefore `valueChanges` comes useful to do [saving when the form is dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545842/how-to-submit-a-template-driven-angular-form-without-any-submit-button) etc.

***Hint**: Property of `AbstractControl` means you can attach these events to either `FormControl`, `FormArray` or `FormGroup`*

Example:
component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <h2 class="text-center">Registration Form</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="first Name" formControlName="firstName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="last Name" formControlName="lastName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" formControlName="email">
        <span *ngIf="form.controls['email']?.errors?.required">This field is required</span>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div *ngIf="form.valid">
        Valid form
    </div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        firstName: ['', Validators.required],
        lastName: [''],
        email: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        console.log('valueChanges Form value ' + value);
    });

    this.form.statusChanges.subscribe((status) => {
        console.log('statusChanges Status is ' + status);
    });
}
```

[image]

[A detailed comparison can be found here](https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-valuechanges-and-statuschanges).