# Angular 9 listen to form pristine change

Tags: angular, forms, valuechangelistener

I want to listen to the first change by the user in a form,
what I need is something like this:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
            return validationForm.$pristine;
        }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
```

but in angular 9.

I tried using valueChanges

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((result) => { })
```

but it emit on each change in the form build too.
how can I subscribe only to the first user's change?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an RxJS pipe like `first` or `take` and subscribe to that.

For example:

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(first()).subscribe((result) => { })
```

or if you wanted to listen to the first 5 changes you could do this:

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(take(5)).subscribe((result) => { })
```

In case what you're trying to do is validation related you may want to look at status change instead. [This answer gives a very short explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51506294/5481110)

Adding a minimal [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2prxgs?file=src/app/app.component.ts) of what I understand you are trying to achieve

Comment: but when I did it it emits in the first changes of the form - for each add control to the form too and not only for the user's changes

Comment: Assuming that you are manually adding each control you could always place this subscription after you're done adding your controls

Comment: it is not a reactive form, I am not adding the controls via type script, I adding it in the html page

Comment: I have added a minimal example, might help make things clearer